# How to answer if the interviewer wants me to be his gay partner?

Tags: interviewing

I have been attending many mock interview sessions in university.Yesterday the interviewer asked me "will you be my gay partner?". First of all I never expected such a question.Secondly, I was trying to figure out if the interviewer is not serious.But couldn't.

Then I thought to mock him or trigger a joke on the subject.But I was really blank.
Although I know he wasn't serious, how to answer such absurd questions?

PS:Interviewer is one of the faculty members of the university

Comment: You would never an encounter a question like this in a real interview, so I think this question is more about how to respond to a professor asking you an unprofessional question. Because of that, and since it's about the interactions between a student and a professor, I would suggest this gets migrated to Academia.

Comment: It sounds to me like your professor was trying to give you some practice handling yourself if an interviewer gives you an outrageous question to try to fluster you. His choice of question could have been more realistic,  but it did it's job.

Comment: see also: [How to handle “absurd” interview questions?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13085/how-to-handle-absurd-interview-questions)

Comment: How would you handle "will you marry me?" from an interviewer of the opposite sex?

Comment: @KateGregory I'll say : I am really dedicated to my work and I prefer not to mix my personal and workplace relationships .

Comment: @joeyrohan sounds like a good answer, no? The "gay" part is not what's shocking, it's the "partner" part and you already know how to answer that, it seems.

Comment: Well it depends. Are you gay?

Comment: An interviewer who asks you for a date or a relationship during your interview could very well end up canned if word came back to the company. I'd probably say with a tight smile "I came here to interview for a position not a relationship. The only prepared answers I have for this type of questions  is 'no'"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Excuse me?"

It's perhaps customary to assume first that you misheard the question. This is also a polite way to get them to reconsider and save face. Should they reiterate the question, then... I have no idea. In the US, the "proper" thing to do would be to talk with the HR of the company about it. The person would then likely be disciplined. Likely fired.

For such a clear violation and my personality, I would definitely consider it. I also might just let it go and decline any offer made. If it were clearly a joke, I might laugh it off, but I have no idea how I could.

Even for a mock interview, I might find such a question (or interviewer) offensive enough to take action depending on the tone and circumstance.

Answer (score 5):

Wow.  I really hope you never get that question for real.  However, one of the trick's I've learned for questions like this that delve into areas you don't want to answer or are not legally obligated to answer is to redirect it to something useful.

For example, for this question, I might turn it around by stating, "If you are asking me about my worklife balance/dedication to the job/whatever..." and continue with the new line of thought.

In this case, I might answer, "If you are asking me about how I feel about workplace relationships, I prefer not to get involved with them as I want to remain dedicated to the job at hand and avoid the complications the usually crop up in such a situation."

I see this type of question coming from two angles: 1. the recruiter is interested in you "romantically" or 2. the company wants to see how you handle absurb situations.  Regardless of the angle, I think this type of question skirts a little too close to a quid pro qou type of sexual harrassment (at least in the US), and would cause me to question my desire to work for this company.  There are better ways to get a date and determine how a future employee acts in an absurd situation.

So bottom line is redirect the question to something more appropriate and/or reassess whether you actually want to work for the firm in question.